# Convert a word document to wiki page using sharepoint 2010

Tags: wiki, wiki-pages, word-automation

Is there any free solution available  to convert Word documents to SharePoint 2010 Wiki Pages?

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2010, Microsoft added a new service called [`AddWikiPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.addwikipage%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to the Lists web service.  With a little bit of Visual Basic code, you can use the [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object provided by Microsoft's XML SDK, to add new Wiki pages with custom content.

Add a reference to "Microsoft XML, v6.0" in the Tools -> References menu in your Visual Basic Editor, and then use something like the code below.

```
Dim objXMLHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Dim strListNameOrGuid As String
Dim strPageUrl As String
Dim strWikiContent As String
Dim strSoapBody As String

Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

strListNameOrGuid = "My List Name or GUID"
strPageUrl = "Page URL Here"
strWikiContent = "Wiki Content Here (including markup)"


objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", "http://myserver/mysite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", False
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/AddWikiPage"

strSoapBody = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " _
  & "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' " _
  & "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><AddWikiPage " _
  & "xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><strListName>" & strListNameOrGuid _
  & "</strListName><listRelPageUrl>" & strPageUrl & "</listRelPageUrl>"
  & "<wikiContent>" & strWikiContent & "</wikiContent></AddWikiPage></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

objXMLHTTP.send strSoapBody

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    ' Do something with response
End If

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: great...you could please let me know if you've posted the complete article somewhere..

Comment: No. This is just a snippet of code that I have used in the past.  Is there something else you need help with as part of this?  I'll see what I can do if so.

Answer (score 2):

Take a Look to the sharepointwikiplugin Project on Codeplex. I'm using this to convert our Word Documention in Sharepoint Wiki pages.

https://sharepointwikiplugin.codeplex.com/

(Note that I am the creator of the plugin)

Comment: can you please advice on how i can install your plugin to SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SharePoint 2010/13 server then there is indeed an out of the box way of achieving this using Document Conversion Services.  It's free in the sense it's included in you server licensing but if you're on Foundation you are out of luck.  I have written a blog article on how to set it up in SP2013 but the process is much the same in SP2010.

http://www.kaboodlekonnect.com/colin/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=19

The problem with Document Conversion Services is that it has one major flaw and that is that it doesn't process embedded content including images.  This makes it next to useless unless you are publishing Word documents with no graphics!

Words without picture in a wiki makes for very dull reading :(

Check out the Word to Wiki module of Kaboodle Renditions if you want to do this properly.

http://www.kaboodlekonnect.com/Pages/Word-to-Wiki.aspx

Comment: i have downloaded the wsp files for the kaboodlekonnect , then i deploy the farm features, then inside the site collection i activate the features. but currently when i upload a document to my documents library i can not find option to convert to wiki ?

Comment: Hi John, there are a few configuration steps to go through. First you need to set up a publishing location to tell the system where you want to send documents and then you have to make that publishing location available to source libraries.  It is all documented here https://kaboodlekonnect-public.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?guestaccesstoken=FIhugBs%2b%2b5SvSwX8QZRQ%2fm70Z0pBj5Ir%2fJfiaIA0OUs%3d&folderid=087c58402cad94fcc9e7dd45146b7a757&action=view